# GITLAB Repo clone to Google Could Storage

Tags: gitlab, yaml, google-cloud-storage

This is documentation which I'm currently using: https://gitlab.com/help/ci/quick_start/README

Setup .gitlab-ci.yml file to push the project to Google Cloud Storage Bucket

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can 'push' to Google Cloud Storage, per se. Cloud Storage isn't a Git backend. What is your purpose for pushing code to Cloud Storage - for backups, or to 'deploy' it for some application purpose?

Assuming it's for some deployment process, you could install and use the Google-provided [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command. GitLab CI automatically checks out your code repository on the runner at the beginning of the job. Then you would specify the files to move to Cloud Storage. For example, if you wanted to move everything you could simply run `gsutil cp * gs://my-bucket`.